# How to display array of JSON objects in a table

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have a JSON array of objects, which I want to dispaly all of it into a table, but somewhere I'm messing up with something.

> **Problem Statement:** Display JSON array of nested objects in a table including all of its contents.

**JSON Data**:

```
{
"loadStops": [{
    "id": 1,
    "sequence": 1,
    "type": "P",
    "stop": {
        "companyId": 148,
        "companyCode": "FWS",
        "legalName": "Frontier WHSE",
        "locations": [{
            "id": 149,
            "city": "PortLavaca",
            "state": "TX",
            "contacts": [{
                "id": 150,
                "medium": "MA",
                "serviceLocator": "000-000-0000",
                "prefered": false,
                "action": 0
            }],
            "action": 0
        }],
        "action": 0
    },
    "apptType": "WDO",
    "appointmentNo": null,
    "commodities": [{
        "id": 0,
        "commodity": "Food",
        "action": 0
    }],
    "action": 0
}, {
    "id": 1,
    "sequence": 1,
    "type": "P",
    "stop": {
        "companyId": 148,
        "companyCode": "FWS",
        "legalName": "Frontier WHSE",
        "locations": [{
            "id": 149,
            "city": "PortLavaca",
            "state": "TX",
            "contacts": [{
                "id": 150,
                "medium": "MA",
                "serviceLocator": "000-000-0000",
                "prefered": false,
                "action": 0
            }],
            "action": 0
        }],
        "action": 0
    },
    "apptType": "WDO",
    "appointmentNo": null,
    "commodities": [{
        "id": 0,
        "commodity": "Food",
        "action": 0
    }],
    "action": 0

}]
```

}

Please guide me how do I write the code for bootstrap table to achieve all the contents inside the table.

**TABLE**:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-hover table-sm">
            <tr>
                <th>headers</th>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td> data </td>
                <td>
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td> nested data etc.. </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>


        </table>
```

Please enlighten my misunderstanding, I'll be thankful to you.
**Thanks**

Comment: What have you tried? Are you aware of `ng-repeat`?

Comment: Do want to show entire JSON as it is into a table? What do you mean by "all of it"?

Comment: @Mawg yes I know about ng-repeat, but it shows one data cell multiple times...

Comment: @AnandG Yes I want all of the information, we may exclude actions and ids.

Comment: @Mawg I tried ng-repeat, and *ngFor, but not useful for me. Due to complexity of object I'm not getting the actual point...

Comment: ngFor if for Angular, not AngularJS. Angular is another, different framework. You ned ng-repeat, and you need to nest ng-repeat inside ng-repeat, just like you would nest for loops in any programming language to loop through an array contained in another array. Show what you tried. We won't do your homework.

Comment: I am going to edit the question with the code that I have tried... Please give me some time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
      I am just giivng a sample to iterate over nested data:
      $scope.value= yourJson;
      $spope.displayVal= $scope.value.loadStops;
      <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-sm">
            <tr ng-repeat="data in displayVal">
                <th>{{data.id}}</th>
                <!-- show data what you want-->
            </tr>

            <tr ng-repeat="data in displayVal">
                <td> data </td>
                <td>
                    <table>
                        <tr ng-repeat="newData in data.stop.location">
                            <td> nested data etc.. </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>


        </table>
```